# Visual Studio 2022 keeps reverting to an old version during publishing

Tags: visual-studio, publish

I am trying to publish my MVC site into local folder.
While clicking Publish I get an error that publish can't be done, because one file is missing. The missing file is the file I've deleted since last publish - VS is trying to restore it and simultaneously deletes 2 new files by itself without asking for permission - I am forced to recover them from git every try because VS just permanently deletes them.

I've changed publish folder localisation, cleaned and rebuilt solution, created two new publish profiles (.pubxml), checked the option to delete old files even though the destination folder is empty.
No matter what I do VS is doing same thing over and over.
I am clueless what to do next.